# Magent2: Magento Cache Storage and Flush Magento Cache - what do they do?

Tags: magento2, cache

**Magento Cache Storage** what cache does it delete? what is his role?

**Flush Magento Cache** what cache does it delete? what is his role?

https://goo.gl/hUkAbw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the cache location (like "/tmp/") or service (like Memcache) is shared with other applications. "Flush Magento Cache" removes only those entries that Magento reliably tracks as it's own. "Flush Cache Storage" clears everything but might affect other applications if they're using it.

Normally the location is "var/cache/" in Magento's folder so is not shared after all. It is safe to use either button. Sometimes (rarely) entries are not clearly tagged or Magento loses track of them and only the second button has an effect on them. I tend to use the second button when I'm having difficulty tracking down the cause of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Flush Magento Cache**

Removes all items in the default Magento cache (var/cache) and the var/full_page cache that have a Magento tag

**Flush Cache Storage**

Removes all items in the cache. This is the equivalent of deleting the entire contents of the cache folder on the server.If your system uses an alternate cache location, any cached files used by other applications will be removed.